# Capture Wildfly shutdown hook

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

In standalone java applications it is easy to know when your application shuts down

```
public class ShutDownHook 
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() 
    { 
      public void run() 
      { 
        System.out.println("Shutdown Hook is running !"); 
      } 
    }); 
    System.out.println("Application Terminating ..."); 
  } 
}
```

What are the options to catch this event in Wildfly application server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use a [ServletContextListener](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).  This is a class within a web application that listens to startup (`contextInitialized`) and shutdown (`contextDestroyed`) events **of the webapp**.  Your code would be something like:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Application Terminating ..."); 
    }
}
```

This is not 100% what you want in that if the webapp that this is installed in is, for example, undeployed, Wildfly is still running but your webapp is not.  But if your environment is such that there is only one webapp or if you can put this code into a webapp that must be running then this will work fine.  Note that this is standard JEE code so you can run this in any container that supports servlets.